# Magento Add to cart button in row with grouped Products

Tags: magento-1.9, grouped-products

In magento 1 I want to add Add to cart button with qty .Is it possible please see the attached screen shot[image]

```
Any Help Appreciated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its Possible Follow the Below Link

```
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/add-to-cart-button-next-to-each-grouped-item
```